# Ruby on Rails + Android distance calculator

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a Ruby on Rails project which interacts with an Android Application I created. It is a Geocaching app (for a school project). I have a table that records an `Item` with the fields of `name`, `user_id`, `found`, `longitude`, and `latitude`. I was able to make the android application create a new record with these details.

I am adding the functionality of calculating the distance between the client (android phone) and one of the items of the list. Should this functionality be done on the client side or server side? If server side, then how would it be done?

Comment: Anywhere would do; doing it on the client side will avoid an unnecessary network call. See the formula to compute the distance: http://xebee.xebia.in/2010/10/28/working-with-geolocations/

Comment: @etienne Location.distanceBetween is a better choice for Android. One line, no bugs.

Comment: @MaciejGórski Indeed.

Comment: I'd like to recommend @MaciejGórski's way. If you need some advance process such as finding the nearest clients around an item, you should do it in server side. You can try some gems: http://geokit.rubyforge.org/, https://github.com/jlecour/geokit-rails3 or  http://www.rubygeocoder.com/